# PLE Muy Alto SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, vb6

Sigo buscando optimizar el servidor SQL SERVER y ahora me topo con que mi PLE esta demasiado (Dejo una imagen de este)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya hice la reindexacion, reconstrucción de indices y nada, ya utilice los querys de ola hallengren para la optimizacion pero no se ve gran avance, cuando veo el problema que me reportan los usuarios es este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en un servidor debian esta la maquina virtual windows server 2008 r2 con 30 gbs de ram y 2 ssd de 500 gbs,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El hecho de que tengas un PLE es un buen síntoma de un sistema saludable. El problema solo resulta cuando es el caso inverso y el PLE es un valor bajo, lo que indica una falta de memoria.

Parece que lo que tienes es un ejemplo del [problema XY](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3360/qu%C3%A9-es-el-problema-xy), por lo que sería mejor que analices que está haciendo el Form_KeyPress del modulo Login para identificar que está teniendo una respuesta lenta que genera el timeout.

Comment: Ohhh okey okey... creo que ya lo entiendo ...